# Send bidirectional signal from bluetooth PCM to loopback to use it in linphone

Tags: alsa, linphone

I have a bluetooth-speaker (with microphone) connected to my system. I am using bluez 5.50 and bluealsa 1.3.1 and my *~/.asoundrc* currently looks like this:

```
pcm.!default {
  type asym
  playback.pcm "looptest"
  capture.pcm "looprec"
}

pcm.looptest {
        type plug
        slave {
                pcm {
                        type bluealsa
                        device E4:22:A5:58:09:95
                        profile "a2dp"
                }
        }
        hint {
                show on
                description "Calisto"
        }
}

ctl.looptest {
        type bluealsa
}

pcm.looprec {
        type plug
        slave {
                pcm {
                        type bluealsa
                        interface "hci0"
                        device E4:22:A5:58:09:95
                        profile "sco"
                }
        }
        hint {
                show on
                description "Calisto REC"
        }
}
ctl.looprec {
        type bluealsa
}
```

When playing audio with aplay the bluetoothspeaker is used as default, so I only have to type `aplay soundfile.wav`. Also when recording audio using `arecord -f cd record.wav` the sound gets recorded correctly.

My main problem is, that when using linphone, only "real" soundcards can be selected as playback/capture devices. What somehow helped was to create an alsa-loopback device. When starting `alsaloop -P "hw:Loopback,1,0" -C "looptest" -t 500000 -d` and then making a call in linphone, I can hear the voice of the callee. But the callee can not hear my voice, which is obvious, as until now, I did not configure a way of the microphone to the loopback device.

How to create this channel? I tried `alsaloop -P "hw:Loopback,1,1" -C "looprec" -t 500000 -r 44100` and also tried several other loopback index-combinations like 0,0 0,1 1,0 but none did the trick. As my current alsa-knowledge is very limited, any hints what I might do wrong? Maybe even the Loopback solution is not needed and the trick can be done with some asoundrc-magic? Or are there other solutions? The only thing I want to avoid is Pulseaudio, as it does not work well with bluealsa

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved the problem by using pulseaudio which correctly worked with the Bluetooth speaker and also is supported by linphone.

In case anyone is interested in my summary, how to connect to Bluetooth speakers and make calls with linphone under a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian Stretch have a look at https://gist.github.com/stefan-wegener/db61bd83a19b4901a2dbc6d78e237b63